# Flutter get unique device id iOs

Tags: ios, flutter, uuid, uniqueidentifier

I am trying to make an application that when user logged in once, user will not log in again. In Android, i can get Android ID but in iOS, i cannot get anything unique. When user deletes the app, unique id changes. I tried to get `identifierForVendor` but it changes too. Is there a solution to get a uuid does not change when user deletes the app?

Comment: Apple has gone to great lengths to prevent you getting unique device identifiers.  You can add a UUID to the keychain.  This will persist across app reinstalls but not if the user erases their device entirely

Comment: Thanks, i found a library to add uuid to the keychain (flutter_keychain). Have a good day!